# Make outliers of a box plot the minimum and maximum of the whiskers in R?

Tags: r, plot, boxplot, outliers

I'd like to make the outliers of the box plot below the end of the whiskers, instead of points. I know this changes the Q1 and Q3 calculations, but is there an easy way to include ALL outliers in the plot as part of the whiskers?

[image]

Comment: Please add the data and the code to generate your image. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: If you use unconventional boxplots like this, be sure to mention in the caption that whiskers extend to full range of data.  (In fact its always good practice to state explicitly what the hinges and whiskers are, since this varies).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what the range option does. Try setting range = 0.